# Checking file existence before creating if it does not exist

Tags: java, file

Ok so I know that there are multiples question of this, but I cannot find the answer that I am looking for sorry for creating a similar one.

Anyways my problem is that I need to check an existence of a file if it is already created or not, but the problem is on my code I obviously making the file first before I am able to check if it exist or not.

```
File createFile = new File ("//path/name.txt");
```

I've read somewhere that that line should not make a file without the:

```
createFile.createNewFile();
```

But when I tested it and on my program, my program was creating the file even without the `createNewFile()` method with that said. I'm confused on how would I be able to check an existence of a file without of course having it pre-created.

Here is the partial code:

```
File newFile = new File ("C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/Keys.txt");
        BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (newFile));
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (newFile));

        if (newFile.exist())
        {
            System.out.print("File is existing");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the check to before you create the file writer which will create the file if it doesn't exist.

```java
File newFile = new File ("C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/Keys.txt");

if (newFile.exist()) {
    System.out.print("File is existing");
}

BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (newFile));
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (newFile));
```

Comment: for someone's sake! why i ddnt thought of that! grr! will try that and be back.

Comment: ha! thank you! your a life saver! that was the solution I mis looked that i am instancing it using filewriter! thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`new File ("//path/name.txt");` is *not* 'making the file' if it does not exist. `.exist()` will return `false` if the file does not exist.

Comment: ok I know that that's why I created this question. you see at the partial code. I tried removing all but the partial code and run the program and viola! the Keys.txt is in the desktop. Makes me think that, that line makes the file.

Comment: He creates the file before doing the .exists() by instantiating FileWriter with the File object as the constructor parameter.